# Vuepress can't find module Require stack:

Tags: node.js, vuepress

I'm getting this error when I use the command yarn dev
is there any way to fix this?

```
PS C:\Users\Maximiliano\Desktop\guia front-end method\docs> yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.19
$ vuepress dev src
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'chalk'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Maximiliano\Desktop\guia front-end method\docs\node_modules\@vuepress\shared-utils\lib\datatypes.js
- C:\Users\Maximiliano\Desktop\guia front-end method\docs\node_modules\@vuepress\shared-utils\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\Maximiliano\Desktop\guia front-end method\docs\node_modules\vuepress\lib\checkEnv.js
- C:\Users\Maximiliano\Desktop\guia front-end method\docs\node_modules\vuepress\cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Maximiliano\Desktop\guia front-end method\docs\node_modules\@vuepress\shared-utils\lib\datatypes.js:7:33)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Maximiliano\\Desktop\\guia front-end method\\docs\\node_modules\\@vuepress\\shared-utils\\lib\\datatypes.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Maximiliano\\Desktop\\guia front-end method\\docs\\node_modules\\@vuepress\\shared-utils\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Maximiliano\\Desktop\\guia front-end method\\docs\\node_modules\\vuepress\\lib\\checkEnv.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Maximiliano\\Desktop\\guia front-end method\\docs\\node_modules\\vuepress\\cli.js'
  ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

[Snapshot of the above error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz8Kp.png)

Comment: Looks similar to [VusJS Vuesax 4 Error: Cannot find module 'chalk'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72417000) or maybe [Error with chalk module installing Vue-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50661363/3744182).  Do either answer your question?

Comment: Nope. I just want to create a vuepress page for documentation but I still get this error